# Transaction won't rollback

Tags: sql-server, transactions, try-catch, rollback

I have the following transaction. I want it to rollback if the SUM of points are not equal to 4000 and to COMMIT if it is. I execute the transaction and the number of points is not equal to 4000. But the transaction is executed nonetheless. Why is that?

```
BEGIN TRAN [Whist]

BEGIN TRY

 END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

IF (SELECT SUM(Point) FROM dbo.Players) <> 4000 

      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Whist]

  END CATCH

IF (SELECT SUM(Point) FROM dbo.Players) = 4000 

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run this SQL 2 ways.  Once with @sum_of_points set to 4000 which will commit the transaction.  Second time with @sum_of_points set to 4001 which will rollback the transaction.

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    declare @sum_of_points          int=4000;

    IF (@sum_of_points <> 4000)
        throw 50000, 'Not equals 4000 so do not commit the transaction', 1;
    commit transaction;
    print ('transaction was committed')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     print ('transaction has been rolled back');
END CATCH
```